# How to get a full $m$-by-$m$ matrix $U$ from a thin SVD?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, least-squares, svd

I am using function `gsl_linalg_SV_decomp` provided by the GNU Scientific Library to solve a least-squares problem

$$\min \|Ax-b\|_2$$

where $A \in \mathbb R^{m \times n}$. The procedure is to first find the SVD of $A$

$$A = U\Sigma V^T$$

where $U \in \mathbb R^{m \times m}$ and $V \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ are orthogonal, i.e., $U^TU = UU^T = I_m$ and $V^TV = VV^T = I_n$.

However, `gsl_linalg_SV_decomp` returns a **thin** SVD, i.e., it provides a $U \in \mathbb R^{m \times n}$. Therefore, I need to extend the thin matrix $U$ to a full orthogonal matrix. I've been thinking about randomly appending some orthonormal columns to $U$, but I'm not sure if it is appropriate.

---

**Update:** After some derivations, I found that a thin SVD is actually enough for solving the least-squares problem if the residual will be ignored. But In my problem, there is a constraint $\|Ax-d\| < \gamma$  and a full SVD is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have a tall matrix $\mathrm U_1 \in \mathbb R^{m \times n}$, whose $n$ columns are the left singular vectors that span the column space of rank-$n$ matrix $\rm A$. To obtain a tall matrix $\mathrm U_2 \in \mathbb R^{m \times (m-n)}$, whose $m-n$ columns are the left singular vectors that span the left null space of $\rm A$, find an **orthornormal** basis of the (right) null space of $\mathrm U_1^\top$ using, say, the RREF.

Comment: Could you please explain it a bit more concretely? I'm quite new to linear algebra.

Comment: @Shindou What you want is $m-n$ unit vectors orthogonal to the $n$ columns of $\rm U_1$ and to each other.

Comment: This implementation seems non-trivial, is that the standard way?

Comment: @Shindou If you  really need the full SVD (and so far, we only have your word on that, despite your being admittedly new at linear algebra), why don't you use a different library which can provide the full SVD, such as LAPACK http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node53.html ?

Comment: @Shindou Here's what you can do. Randomly generate $m-n$ vectors in $\mathbb R^m$, project them onto the left null space of $\rm A$ via the projection matrix $\rm P := I_m - U_1 U_1^\top$ and then use Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization.

Comment: I'll try. And, did you mean that the solution of  $U_1^Tx = 0$ gives $U_2$ in your posted answer?

Comment: Assuming that $Rank(A) = n, m > n$, the solution of $U_1^Tx = 0$ should have $m-n$ basis vectors in $R^m$, could I take that as $U_2$?

Comment: @Shindou Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

All you need for least squares or pseudoinverse is the thin SVD. The extra columns in $U$ and $V$ in the full SVD are nulled out in the pseudoinverse $V\Sigma^{-1}U^T$due to the zero entries in the lower right portion of the diagonal of the full $\Sigma^{-1}$.

GNU Scientific Library is providing what most people need (use) for SVD. Calculating the full SVD is more "expensive" than thin SVD.

Comment: well... I'm sorry that what I posted is just part of the story... The other part is about adding a constraint... and I really need a full matrix $U$.

Comment: What constraint do you need to add?  SVD might not even be the right thing at all if you have a constrained least squares problem. How do you intend to use the full SVD for your constrained problem?

Comment: I'm solving the problem $min_x ||Ax-b||~~ s.t .||Bx -d|| \leq \gamma$, or a reduced problem $min_x ||Ax-b|| ~~s.t.||Ax-d|| \leq \gamma$.

Comment: That can be solved as a Quadratically Constrained Quadratic Program (QCQP), or as a Second Order Cone Problem (SOCP).  There are many available solvers to do this.  Or you can use a convex optimization modeling front end via MATLAB, Python, R, and others to enter it almost as written, and let it transform the problem to the form the solver needs, and call the solver.

Comment: E.g., in CVX under MATLAB: cvx_begin;variable x(n);minimize(norm(A*x-b));norm(B*x-d) <= gamma;cvx_end.  CVX internally transforms this to an SOCP, call the solver, and returns the optimal x and objective value. SVD is not used.

Comment: I just need to solve this **tiny** convex optimization problem, which I can find an analytic solution provided that a full SVD is available... And what if we forget about all the story, and just want to know if randomly appending some orthonormal columns to U is appropriate...

Comment: Can you show us what your solution is, presuming availability of the full SVD?

Comment: ...that would be a long story